# 'DbBackend' object has no attribute 'use_ssl' django

Tags: django, sendmail, backend

I had a django app with version 1.6.5 and updated it to django 1.8 and got the below error when trying to send an email

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/user/user_name/apps/proj/project_name/app_name/core/views.py" in contact_page
  54.       send_mail('Contact from web', body, 'Directories', ["info@project.com"], fail_silently=False)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in send_mail
  62.     return mail.send()
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  303.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/Users/user/user_name/apps/proj/project_name/app_name/mailer/backend.py" in send_messages
  50.         new_conn_created = self.open()
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in open
  46.         connection_class = smtplib.SMTP_SSL if self.use_ssl else smtplib.SMTP

Exception Type: AttributeError at /contact/
Exception Value: 'DbBackend' object has no attribute 'use_ssl'
```

and the view was

```
def contact_page(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      name = form.cleaned_data['name'].encode('utf8')
      phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
      .....
      ....
      send_mail('Contact from web', body, 'Directories', ["info@project.com"], fail_silently=False)
      .......
```

backend.py

```
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend
from mailer.models import Message
from django.conf import settings

class DbBackend(EmailBackend):

    def __init__(self, host=None, port=None, username=None, password=None,
                 use_tls=None, fail_silently=False, **kwargs):
        super(EmailBackend, self).__init__(fail_silently=fail_silently)
        self.host = host or settings.EMAIL_HOST
        self.port = port or settings.EMAIL_PORT
        if username is None:
            self.username = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        else:
            self.username = username
        if password is None:
            self.password = settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
        else:
            self.password = password
        if use_tls is None:
            self.use_tls = settings.EMAIL_USE_TLS
        else:
            self.use_tls = use_tls
        self.connection = None
        # self._lock = threading.RLock()

    def send_messages(self, email_messages):
        """
        Sends one or more EmailMessage objects and returns the number of email
        messages sent.
        """
        if not email_messages:
            return
        for message in email_messages:
            msg = Message()
            msg.email = message
            msg.save()
        # with self._lock:
        new_conn_created = self.open()
        if not self.connection:
            # We failed silently on open().
            # Trying to send would be pointless.
            return
        num_sent = 0
        for message in email_messages:
            sent = self._send(message)
            if sent:
                num_sent += 1
        if new_conn_created:
            self.close()
        return num_sent
```

What might be the problem here ?

Comment: Could you post the email backend defined in `/Users/user/user_name/apps/proj/project_name/app_name/mailer/backend.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your Django application uses a custom email backend (specified by the [EMAIL_BACKEND](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#email-backend) setting), that custom email backend apparently subclasses `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend` and that class has changed between Django 1.6 and Django 1.8 . Your custom email backend is not compatible with the new implementation of `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`.

I would be able to give you a more detailed answer if you would post the `DbBackend` implementation but my guess is that you override `EmailBackend.__init__` without calling `super(DbBackend, self).__init__`.

**Edit**: You are indeed not calling `super(DbBackend, self).__init__` in `EmailBackend.__init__` but `super(EmailBackend, self).__init__`.

`DbBackend`'s version of `__init__` is in fact a copy/paste of the Django 1.6 version of `EmailBackend.__init__` without the lock instantiation.

The easiest solution to your problem would be to not override the `__init__` method. If you don't want locking, don't use the lock in `send_messages` but let it be instantiated.

I do not know why you want to get rid of locking but if you would keep it, the implementation of `DbBackend` would be as simple as:

```
class DbBackend(EmailBackend):
    def send_messages(self, email_messages):           
        if not email_messages:
            return
        for message in email_messages:
            msg = Message()
            msg.email = message
            msg.save()

        super(DbBackend, self).send_messages(email_messages)
```

And it would not break on further Django upgrades.

Comment: I was facing some locking thread errors when sending emails, so i decided to override it and unlock previously